# Linux to Windows cmd

Tags: python, linux, windows, cmd, terminal

How i can it translate to cmd? 
Have to install python env

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export INSTAPAGE_TOKEN='REPLACEME'
export INSTAPAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN='REPLACEME'
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -q -y install python-virtualenv python-dev google-chrome-stable firefox xvfb wamerican exim4
virtualenv .ve
source .ve/bin/activate
```

How i can change apt-key adv ,apt-get update , apt-get -q -y, export and source(?), etc
Thanks

Comment: That script is OS-specific, you can't simply translate it, you need a script for your OS. However, search for "virtualenv-15.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl" on [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) of Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages.

Comment: i just installed linux :)